# how to write sql query in linq with left join

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

```
select 
    pm.GenerationID, srv.ServiceID, srv.ServiceName, srv.ServiceDescription, 
    srv.IsProPack, pm.MonthlyPrice, pm.AnnualPrice, ss.freeExpirationDate 
from 
    tbl_BILLING_PricingModels pm 
    inner join tbl_BILLING_Services srv on pm.ServiceID = srv.ServiceId 
    left join tbl_BILLING_SubscribedServices ss on srv.ServiceID = ss.ServiceId 
        and ss.ClientId='3B345E8B-3E6C-40E6-A4B8-E6371B717018' 
where 
    pm.GenerationID = 5 order by srv.ServiceID
```

How to write linq query?

Answer (score 0):

Please, note that i have no possibility to test this but if it is not correct, you can follow this direction:

```
var p = from pm in tbl_BILLING_PricingModels 
        join srv in tbl_BILLING_Services on pm.ServiceID equals srv.ServiceId nto res
        from ss tbl_BILLING_SubscribedServices on srv.ServiceID = ss.ServiceId && ss.ClientId='3B345E8B-3E6C-40E6-A4B8-E6371B717018' 
        where pm.GenerationID = 5 
        order by srv.ServiceID
        select new { pm.GenerationID,
        srv.ServiceID,
        srv.ServiceName,
        srv.ServiceDescription,
        srv.IsProPack }
```